# Selenium Grid 2 for RemoteWebDriver gives an exception for Chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, remotewebdriver

Please see my grid batch file. (I added both chrome binary and chrome driver location in my path)

My code works perfectly if I use firefox but for chrome and IE it throws an Exception given below. I am sure I am missing a very trivial thing but I am not able to figure it out.

```
Batch file

set HERE=C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads
set JAVA_HOME=%HERE%\jdk-7u13-windows-x64
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%CHROME_DRIVER_LOC%;%IE_DRIVER_LOC%;%CHROME_BINARY_LOC%;%PATH%;
set SELENIUM_VERSION=2.29.0
set CHROME_VERSION=chromedriver_win_26.0.1383.0
set HUB_URL=http://localhost:4444/grid/register
set CHROME_DRIVER_LOC=C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\chromedriver_win_26.0.1383.0\chromedriver.exe
set IE_DRIVER_LOC=C:\Users\Adminstrator\Downloads\IEDriverServer_x64_2.31.0\IEDriverServer.exe
set CHROME_BINARY_LOC=C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
start java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.29.0.jar -role hub
start java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.29.0.jar -role node
-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=%CHROME_DRIVER_LOC% -hub %HUB_URL% -port 5556

My sample code:
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setBrowserName(DesiredCapabilities.chrome().getBrowserName());
URL url = new URL(“<http://localhost:4444/wd/hub>”);
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(url, capabilities);

// And now use this to visit Google
driver.get(“web page”);

Exception I am getting :

Exception in thread “main” org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list
Command duration or timeout: 608 milliseconds
Build info: version: ’2.29.0′, revision: ’58258c3′, time: ’2013-01-17 22:47:00′
System info: os.name: ‘Windows Server 2008 R2′, os.arch: ‘amd64′, os.version: ’6.1′, java.version: ’1.7.0_13′
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:187)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:533)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:216)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:111)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:129)
at test.Test.main(Test.java:32)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see ….
```

Please help! I couldn’t understand what I am doing wrong. I have been struggling with this from quite some time now. Any help will be very much appreciated.

```
Thanks
Sushmita
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, the below line is the culprit

```
start java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.29.0.jar -role node
-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=%CHROME_DRIVER_LOC% -hub %HUB_URL% -port 5556
```

Use below line and check if it is working.

```
start java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=%CHROME_DRIVER_LOC% -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.29.0.jar -role webdriver -hub %HUB_URL% -port 5556
```

Answer (score 1):

With Chrome and IE, you will need to define a driver executable path, you can fine the files here:
http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list
and http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list

Then you will need something like this before you create a new ChromeDriver:
String chromeDriverPath = "C:\ChromeDriver.exe";
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromeDriverPath);

Answer (score 1):

A very simple workaround is to place the IEDriverServer and the chromedriver executables in the same folder as your selenium jar file